# Error! App '255850' state is is 0x2 after update job

Tags: hosting, rust

**This issue has been solved. I was having an issue with my local CDN after a major internet outage that spanned over two weeks.**

I am trying to create a new Rust server for my friend and I to play on, but have run into an issue while trying to create it.

I install SteamCMD, no problems there. However, when I create a .bat file to start downloading the Rust dedicated server, it repeats the same message for around two minutes,

> Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress 0.00 (0 / 0)

thereafter failing with the error message:

> Error! App '255850' state is is 0x2 after update job.

The CMD session then outputs that the work queue is not empty and quits the prompt.

I have allowed my download queue on Steam to finish and I have disabled my firewall to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your reply, but this error has since been fixed. It turns out there was a problem with my local CDN, after a major internet outage that affected my area.

My apologies for not clarifying that I no longer require assistance on this issue.
And again, thank you for the reply.

Comment: No problem -- glad you got it working :) That was a strange error, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The values need to be converted from hexadecimal to decimal (0x at the beginning denotes hex), but 0x0-0x9 are just 0-9 so they're simple. The Steam appmanifest status values can be found [in this document from the Lutris app](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/blob/master/docs/steam.rst) on GitHub. In your case the app is not downloading properly so it ends up with a state of "2" or "UpdateRequired" as it still wants to update.

Have you tried just using SteamCMD directly without a script? It would help confirm it's an issue with Steam/installing the server instead of with your BAT script.